# Multiple swaggerUi with a single express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to find a solution to have multiple swaggerUi documentation with a single express app.

I'm using :

```
"typescript": "^2.5.2",
"swagger-tools": "^0.10.1",
"express": "^4.15.3",
"express-openapi": "^1.0.1",
```

My swagger doc file is partly generated with the project file architecture.

How can I do that ?

EDIT ---

For now I'm initializing swaggerUi like this :

```
const openapi = Openapi.initialize({
    paths: openApiPaths,
    expressApp,
    swaggerApiDoc,
  });
const openApiSpec: any = openapi.apiDoc;
app.use(swaggerUI(openApiSpec));
```

Where `openApiPaths` contain the `paths:{}` of swagger doc

Comment: You want to expose the same swagger doc twice on two different swagger ui url ?

Comment: To be precise. I need to expose different swagger doc on different swaggerUI. Example : I have a global swagger with 50 paths, 1 client need only 10 paths of these, another client need only 8paths from the global swagger .. etc

Answer (score 6):

As of 2022, you can add multiple swagger UI to the same application.
From the [swagger-UI documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express):

> To run 2 swagger ui instances with different swagger documents, use the serveFiles function instead of the serve function. The serveFiles function has the same signature as the setup function.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocumentOne = require('./swagger-one.json');
const swaggerDocumentTwo = require('./swagger-two.json');

var options = {}

app.use('/api-docs-one', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocumentOne, options), swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocumentOne));

app.use('/api-docs-two', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocumentTwo, options), swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocumentTwo));
```

Answer (score 1):

A year late, but still valid:

```
async function initialize (app) {

  const authenticationSpec = path.join(__dirname,'api/authentication.yaml');
  const authenticationMiddleware = await useSwaggerMiddlewares(authenticationSpec, {
    router: routerOptions,
    validator: validatorOptions,
  });
  // NOTE the metadata must be mounted at root level!
  app.use(authenticationMiddleware.metadata);
  app.use('/v2/authentication', authenticationMiddleware.validator);
  app.use('/v2/authentication', authenticationMiddleware.router);
  app.use('/v2/authentication', authenticationMiddleware.ui);

  const mainSpec = path.join(__dirname,'api/swagger.yaml');
  const mainMiddleware = await useSwaggerMiddlewares(mainSpec, {
    router: routerOptions,
    validator: validatorOptions,
  });
  app.use(mainMiddleware.metadata);
  app.use(mainMiddleware.validator);
  app.use(mainMiddleware.router);
  app.use(mainMiddleware.ui);

  // Start the server
  http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, () => console.log(`server lintening on port ${serverPort}`);
}

initialize(app);
```

With useSwaggerMiddlewares defined here

```
module.exports = function useSwaggerMiddlewares (swaggerSpec, {
  router: routerOptions, validator: validatorOptions,
}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      // The Swagger document (require it, build it programmatically, fetch it from a URL, ...)
      const spec = fs.readFileSync(swaggerSpec, 'utf8');
      const swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);

      // Initialize the Swagger middleware
      swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, (middleware) => {
        try {
          return resolve({
            // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
            metadata: middleware.swaggerMetadata(),
            // Validate Swagger requests
            validator: middleware.swaggerValidator(validatorOptions),
            // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
            router: middleware.swaggerRouter(routerOptions),
            // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
            ui: middleware.swaggerUi()
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return reject(error);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple apis on a single express server, you just have to be sure 
 `basePath` doesn't overlap each other.

ref : https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/530

```
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(doc1, function (mw1) {
  // Do stuff with first middleware

  swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(doc2, function (mw2) {
    // Do stuff with second middleware

    // Repeat...
  });
});
```

ref : https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/513

Comment: Hm I see, but how to set that up ? using multiple swaggerui middlewares ?